# Overflow hidden border over slider images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

this is the slider i'm trying to modify:
http://webkunst.comeze.com/

And this is the overflow with border that I want to achieve:
[image]

The problem is that I have tried everything to make the image work with the container overflow:hidden but it's not possible, I have tried with position relative, of all the container divs and so on.

Can someone help me out? The transparent border aren't a must but the most important thing is to get the overflow hidden work with the borders.

This is the markup:

```
<div id="home_slider">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li class="home_slide"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="home_slide"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="home_slide"><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="home_slide"><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
    #home_slider {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 880px;
      height: 416px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #home_slider ul#slides {
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    #home_slider ul#slides li {
      margin: 0;
      width: 900px;
      height: 416px;
    }
    .home_box {
      margin-top: 30px;
      float: right;
    }
    .home_box .home_image {
      float: left;
      border: 3px solid #6f6f6f;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-left: 13px;
    }
```

I got the slider from this tutorial:
http://line25.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-image-slideshow-with-jquery-cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the `border-radius` to the `#home_slider` div instead of `#home_slider ul#slides`. For the transparent border, you can use rgba and you will need to apply it to `#home_slider` as well:

```
#home_slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 880px;
    height: 416px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px; /* add this */
    border: 15px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* add something like this for the transparent border */
}
```

**EDIT :** It seems Chrome cannot clip contents to a `border-radius` when the elements are not `position:static`. However, if you can live without the transparent border then you can add this to the same rule above to get the rounded corners, but you must remove the border:

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

Comment: thanks, the border looks nice but the image still shows the borders :(

Comment: I also removed the border radius from ul#slides

Comment: @diego: Are you sure? Can you please update the example site so that I can see your code, because I am pretty sure it works. Also what browser are you in?

Comment: It looks good in IE9 and Firefox. But it looks like it might be a bug in Chrome. I've updated the answer.